# Веб-сервер на PHP (не через сокеты)

Tags: php, http, веб-сервер

Всем приветы.

Давеча получил такое тестовое задание от одной конторы:

> Написать веб-сервер для игры (на PHP).
>   Веб-сервер должен работать по протоколу HTTP (не через сокеты).
>   ...

Попытки уточнить задание были обречены на провал, ответ был один: "В задании все указано".

В связи с этим встал вопрос (риторический, да): Каким образом реализовать веб-сервер на PHP, без использования сокетов, который бы работал по протоколу HTTP? Возможно, я просто не понял определения "веб-сервер" в данном конексте, все может быть, но задача стоит именно так: веб-сервер = PHP + HTTP - сокеты.

Comment: Мне кажется что web-сервер на языке php не пишется.

Comment: `Попытки уточнить задание были обречены на провал, ответ был один: "В задании все указано".` - видимо задание прислал HR))

Comment: Собеседывание на какую должность? На какой язык?

Comment: `ответ был один: "В задании все указано` - значит вам в ту компанию не надо

Comment: Зависит от игры. Если это крестики-нолики, к примеру, то просто: ход -- отправляем запрос на сервер, возвращаем ход компа. и т.д.

Comment: учитывая, что все известные мне реализации http сделаны именно на сокетах, тогда правильный ответ - никак. Но можно попробовать реализовать http на чем то другом (например, на com портах).

Comment: Может они хотели что бы ты написал REST API маршруты и запустил их через встроенный в  php web- сервер  ? http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: вангую, что либо в компании работают сильно хитрые и решили посмотреть, как выкрутиться (тогда им подойдет мой ответ выше и их нужно послать лесом),либо слишком начинающие (тут другие слова подходят, но о них умолчим) и просто отсутствие слова socket  в тексте кода будет достаточно. В этом случае подойдет ответ выше, но их также следует послать.

Comment: @KoVadim Помню я был пьян и делал тз какой то фирме, сделал все правильно, кроме первого задания где нужно было взять средний элемент массива :) я вместо средне арифметического  взял просто элемент из середины ) так как в примере было нечетное число элементов, они написали что не верно, а я сказал, что это не верно поставленная задача и тип если они так тз дают то работать я там не буду :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation `A TCP connection is managed by an operating system through a programming interface that represents the local end-point for communications, the **Internet socket.** `

Comment: Используйте библиотеку, вы сокетами не пользуетесь, библиотека пользуеться :).